# Want to iterate through hashTable keys, use keys() or keySet()?

Tags: java, hashtable

Trying to return all numbers in the hashtable that appear an odd number of times, I've commented the bad line.

Basically I wanted the code to go through the int array and assign it to keys of the hash table, if it appeared again (even times), make boolean false, if it appeared odd number of times boolean would be true. Then I need to iterate through the keys of the hash table and return the keys that have a boolean of true.

```
package practice;

import java.util.*;
/*

You are given an integer array, where all numbers except for TWO numbers appear even number of times. 

Q: Find out the two numbers which appear odd number of times.

*/

public class hashTable{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] test = {2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4};
    List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Hashtable<Integer, Boolean> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>(); 
    Boolean check = true;
    for (int item : test){
        if (!ht.containsKey(item)){
            check = true;
        } else{
            check = false;
            ht.put(item, check);
        }
        }

    for (int item : ht.keySet()){
        if (ht.get(item) == true){
            solution.add(item);
        }
        }
    System.out.println("the result is");
    System.out.println(solution);
    }

 }
```

Comment: As a side comment Hashtable is obsolete and in midst situations you should use HashMap instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never put the item in the hashtable when it is true.

```
for (int item : test){
    if (!ht.containsKey(item)){
        check = true;
    } else{
        check = false;
        ht.put(item, check);
    }
    }
```

Should be

```
for (int item : test){
    if (!ht.containsKey(item)){
        check = true;
    } else{
        check = false;
    }
        ht.put(item, check);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keys()` method returns the set of keys as an Enumeration.

The `keySet()` method returns the set of keys as a Set object.

`!ht.containsKey(item)` is not going to be true , so again this `check = true;` and your ht will be empty.

So you need to add the value to the `ht` for the first time regardless of the `if` conditions

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I have updated the code, it runs but the solution is empty when it should be [5,7]

Answer (score 0):

ht is always empty: when you iterate through test, containsKey is always false, so you never insert into ht.

You're not building ht correctly at all.

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
import java.util.*;
/*

You are given an integer array, where all numbers except for TWO numbers appear even number of times. 

Q: Find out the two numbers which appear odd number of times.

*/

public class hashTable{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] test = {2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4};
    List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Hashtable<Integer, Boolean> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Boolean>(); 
    Boolean check = true;
    for (int item : test){
        if (!ht.containsKey(item)){
            check = true;
        } else{
            System.out.println("else"+item);
            check = false;

        }
        ht.put(item, check);
        }
    for (int item : ht.keySet()){
        System.out.println("output"+item);
        if (ht.get(item) == true){
            solution.add(item);
        }
        }
    System.out.println("the result is");
    System.out.println(solution);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can solve your problem using Streams. A short an neat solutions would be:

```
int[] test = {2, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4};

// Collect to a Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m = 
    Arrays.stream(test).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a));

// Stream the map, filter out the odd ones and collect to a list
final List<Integer> odds = 
    m.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() % 2 != 0)
        .map(e -> e.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you prefer it as a "oneliner"

```
final List<Integer> odds =
        Arrays.stream(test)
                .boxed() // Create a stream of Integers
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a)) // Group by the key
                .entrySet().stream() // Create a stream of the entrySet
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() % 2 != 0) // Keep only the odd ones
                .map(e -> e.getKey()) // Convert Entry to an integer (the key)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect it to a list
```